# Installing MMTK 2.7.8 - Molecular modeling toolkit

Tags: macos, modeling

```
python setup.py install

lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccZn3E25.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build and install a C extension module included with MMTK, Python is looking for the C compiler it was built with.  For OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), the least trouble-prone way to supply this is to install `Xcode 3.2.6`, the most recent (and last) version of Xcode 3.  If you don't already have an installer for it, you can download it for free (after free registration) from the [Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com).  Make sure that the `UNIX Development` sub-package is selected to be installed.

If you have `Xcode 4` for OS X 10.6 installed or some other C compiler, you *might* be able to successfully install the extension module by supplying a CC environment variable with the path to the compiler, for example:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/cc
```

You may also need to supply other variables that reference the compiler path, in particular, `LDSHARED`.